# Video content no longer appears in Webview, even though it was working before! What is going on?

Tags: ssl, javafx, encryption, webview, video-streaming

I have a domain transferred to cloudflare (SSL/TLS encryption mode is Full-strict). This domain points to a server used primarily as video hosting. For the past couple of days I've been noticing that my webview application in javafx, enabled for streaming, no longer displays the videos contained in that hosting. I am not understanding why! Yet if I point the videos to another host that does not use cloudflare services, the videos through the webview are displayed. What is happening? Jdk used jdk1.8.0_202

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Java 1.8.0_351 is current for Oracle's JDK 8.

Comment: With the info given, there is really no way for anybody to replicate your issue, so I expect assistance will be limited.